# PHP file_put_contents()

Tags: php, image, file-upload

How can I get this to provide an actual image?

```
file_put_contents($url,$image);
```

The size, and name are posted to directory correctly, but the image appears broken. Do I need to encode, or decode?

Just to inform you, $image comes from the following:

```
    ob_start();
    echo imagejpeg($image,null,30);
    $image = ob_get_clean();
    ob_end_clean();
    $image = addslashes($image);
```

$image has successfully been posted to mysql as is, but I have been struggling to get it into directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imagejpeg()` outputs the image to the output buffer. You're using `echo imagepeg()` which will output the image then immediately echo the `true/false` return value of your function call.

Further, you're corrupting your image by doing this: `$image = addslashes($image);`, which I imagine is done for the benefit of your database.

What you need is

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($image,null,30);
$image = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents($url,$image);
```

I don't see why you're storing the image in the database **and** in the file system. The filesystem should be good enough: store the path & file name in the database.

If you feel you *must* add the image to the database don't use `addslashes()` but escape it with the function provided by the API you're using, at the point you want to execute the query. You'd be better using prepared statements so that escaping the data is unnecessary.

Comment: Hobo, you rock so much. I have been struggling with this for weeks. *says everyone who asks a stackoverflow question* But, sincerely thank you.

Comment: @AdreamcathcerAdreamcatcher Just realised you have a redundant call to `ob_end_clean()` in your snippet. `ob_get_clean()` does that as part of its activities.  I've now removed it. It may not matter, but if, you've included another `ob_start()` in your code you'd find it was terminated unexpectedly.